# Do nothing in VB

Tags: vb.net

I have to check an Excel file with more than 5000 rows. In certain cases, though, I have nothing to do. How can express it in VB.NET?

```
For r = 196 To 5549  
    If r = 1233 And r = 1745 Then
        'Do nothing
    End If
Next
```

This is an example that what I'd like. How can I do?

Comment: Are you supposed to do something if the condition is false? Then why not reverse it, and *do something*? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can skip the current `For` step by using `Continue For`:

```
For r = 196 To 5549  
    If r = 1233 Or r = 1745 Then
        'Do nothing
        Continue For
    End If

    'Do something
Next
```

---

In case your list of numbers is growing you an also use the following code:

```
For r = 196 To 5549  
    If Array.IndexOf({1233, 1745}, r) > -1 Then
        'Do nothing
        Continue For
    End If

    'Do something
Next
```

> **Hint:** There seems something wrong with your condition. `r` can't be 1233 **and** 1745. It can be only 1233 **or** 1745.